# How to call published property without updating value

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

In SwiftUI, combine I have a published property.

```
@Published
var name: String
```

And when the name is updated it calls an app and set other values.

```
$name
...
...
.assign(to: &$something)
```

Now I want to call this without updating the name at some case

Comment: Could you give example code of use-case?

Comment: Call *what*? Something that you have in the `...`? It's unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @jnpdx when the name is updated it calls an api to fetch some other details. Now when I click a button I want to do the same without changing the name property

Comment: @jnpdx simply 'name = name' solves my need. But I don't think it's good

Comment: Why don't you separate the API call into a function outside the combine chain that you can call on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


class AddPassaround : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var reversed : String = ""
    let passaround = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    init() {
        $name
            .merge(with: passaround)
            .map { String($0.reversed()) }
            .assign(to: &$reversed)
    }


    func doIt() {
        $reversed.sink { print($0) }
        name = "reversedFromSettingName"
        print(name)
        passaround.send("reversedFromPassaround")
        print(name)
    }
}

AddPassaround().doIt()
```

This adds a second publisher called `passaround` and you can invoke the behavior after the `$name` by either publishing a value to name or by passing the value through the `passaround` publisher.